# XAML change TextBlock Margin property based on Rectangle's size

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, blend

I'm trying to create something looking like this :

[image]

It's designed to be an XAML title for VMIX software, video broadcasting purposes.

I'm gonna get a lot of datas from a GSheet, handle in VMIX, and assign those datas to my TextBlocks such as "Candidate", "City" and the Votes %.

From that % I want the bar size to increase/decrease, I managed to do part of that.

But the main issue is to get the % TextBlock margin to fit on the right of the rectangle. 
Anyone knows how I could do that ?

I have never been coding in C#, I have a background in C, C++ and JS, so I've spent my day looking for that purpose and couldn't make it right.

I saw some binding methods that could fit, but I'm unable to use them.

Moreover I'm working on Blend for Visual Studio 2017, and I don't get why I can't run some simple code on it when pressing F5... It's another problem thought.

Thanks a lot for your help.

**EDIT :**

I've reached something new so far, really DIY solution but it's my lsat solution if I can't find better :

*I'll have 2 TextBlock for 1 ProgressBar (Thanks to Chris)*

```
<Grid Margin="0,0,-8,0">
    <TextBlock x:Name="Votes1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="{Binding Text, ElementName=MarginVotes1}" FontSize="72" Width="853" Height="188"><Run Text="6"/><Run Text="00"/></TextBlock>
    <ProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="79" Margin="171,503,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=Votes1}" Background="#FFEA4545"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="MarginVotes1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="171,587,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="72" Height="98" Width="550"><Run Text="8"/><Run Text="0"/><Run Text="0"/><Run Text=","/><Run Text="4"/><Run Text="9"/><Run Text="0"/><Run Text=",0,0"/> 
   </TextBlock>
```

So this works fine, *but I have to prepare before what my "MarginVotes1" value is* (in GoogleSheet).

**The best would be directly in code behind to do something like this :**

CONVERT Votes1.Text to Int STORE in val

SET x to val + DefaultMargin

CONVERT x to String STORE in MarginX

CREATE String MarginVoteStr as MarginX + ",500, 0, 0"

SET Votes1.Margin as MarginVoteStr

Comment: If it were me I'd suggest just styling the actual [progressBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/progressbar-styles-and-templates) control style template to look the way you want it to instead of trying to create from scratch. Would make it more versatile and take less effort to accomplish the goal.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Chris! It looks like a solution to look after. Therefore I have to test if it can be interpreted in the broadcasting software. Moreover I don't get how to set the size of it and my initial goal to have the text margin automatically. Do you have any idea on that?

Comment: Please post your Xaml.  It will help to be able to understand how you are currently getting the above to work so far.

Comment: Hi Jeff! The above doesn't work yet, it's just a draft of my goal. I'm using blend for visual 2017 so for now I have literally 1 line of code in C#. But I'll send it tomorrow as I'm not at the office right now

Comment: I've editted my question so you can see the code

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to WPF. Here's some code I put together that you should be pretty close to what you need.

XAML:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Candidates}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Candidate" Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Height="10" Margin="5, 0" Width="{Binding BarWidth}" Fill="{Binding BarColor}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Percentage, StringFormat=P}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

C#:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Candidates = new List<Candidate> { new Candidate { Name = "Joe", Percentage = .50, BarColor = Brushes.Green},
                                            new Candidate { Name = "Bob", Percentage = .30, BarColor = Brushes.Yellow},
                                            new Candidate { Name = "Sarah", Percentage = .20, BarColor = Brushes.Gray}};
    }
               
    public List<Candidate> Candidates
    {
        get { return (List<Candidate>)GetValue(CandidatesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CandidatesProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CandidatesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Candidates", typeof(List<Candidate>), typeof(MainWindow));
}

public class Candidate
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Percentage { get; set; }
    public Brush BarColor { get; set; }

    //This is just shorter syntax for a readonly property.
    //The multiplier (200) should be whatever length you want a full bar to be
    public double BarWidth => Percentage * 200;
}
```

There are a number of points you should note:

## ItemsControl and DataTemplate

Whenever you need to display multiple data items in WPF, especially if the number of items is variable, you should be using some type of [`ItemsControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol).

An `ItemsControl` takes a collection of some kind and displays each item using a [`DataTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview). An `ItemsControl` creates a new instance of its `ItemTemplate` for every item in its source collection. The link between the data and the visuals is established through [data bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview).

## Layout

Everything between the `<DataTemplate>` tags is the visual layout of a single item.

Notice that I am not using `Margin` to create the desired layout. Instead of using `Margin` in that way, I'm using one of WPFs many [`Panel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/panels-overview) controls: `Grid`. With `Grid` you can define rows and columns like a table.

Each item in my example is a `Grid` with 1 row and 3 columns. The elements that make up the item are placed in that grid using the `Grid.Column` property. Each column has `Width="Auto"`, which means it will grow to accommodate the width of what's inside. `IsSharedSizeScope` and `SharedSizeGroup` make it so that the `Grid`s of each individual item all have the same width for the first column.

## `Candidate` class

This is the class that will be used to store and represent the data being displayed. Note that the property names match the `{Binding ______}` values from the `DataTemplate`.

My example main window has a collection of `Candidate` objects stored in a [dependency property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview). This property is bound to the `ItemsSource` of the `ItemsControl`.

## Overall

The idea is to populate your collection with whatever data items you need and let the `ItemsControl` take care of the rest, thus keeping the data and visuals of the project relatively independent. Even small visual aspects like formatting the percentage value correctly for display can be done using the `DataTemplate` instead of writing the code in C#, as shown using `StringFormat=P`.